# Instances of a class and how to test them

Tags: java, class, instance, multiple-instances

I was just wondering if I made the instances of the class correctly. Also is there any way that I can test the `instances` of the `class`. I tried for example to do `System.out.println(Toddler.getAge())` in my `main` method but I keep getting an `error`.

```
public class Person
{
  private String name;
  private int age;


  public Person()
  {
    name = "No name yet";
    age = 0;
  }

  public Person(String userName, int userAge)
  {
    name = userName;
    age = userAge;
  }

  public static Person createAdult(String name, int age)
  { 
    Person newPerson = new Person("An adult", 21); 
    return newPerson;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }

  public void setName(String first, String last)
  {
    name = first + last;
  }

  public void setName(String wholeName)
  {
    name = wholeName;
  }

  public void setAge(int userAge)
  {
    age = userAge;
  }

  public static Person createToddler(String name, int age)
  {
    Person Toddler = new Person("A toddler", 2); 
    return Toddler;
  }

  public static Person createPreschooler(String name, int age)
  {
    Person Preschooler = new Person("A preschooler", 5);
    return Preschooler;
  }

  public static Person createAdolescent(String name, int age)
  {
    Person Adolescent = new Person("An adolescent", 9);
    return Adolescent;
  }

  public static Person createTeenager(String name, int age)
  {
    Person Teenager = new Person("A teenager", 15);
    return Teenager;
  }


}
```

Comment: easiest way :print something in ur Person() constructor at the end.If object created properly then it will print on console.

Answer (score 1):

You nowhere mentioned how you were using `Toddler.getAge()` in `main` method.
But as per the code of `Person` class, you got to use it like this:

```
System.out.println(Person.createToddler("Tahir", 25).getName());//for name
System.out.println(Person.createToddler("Tahir", 25).getName());//for age
```

This code prints the age and name correctly.
`Person.createToddler("Tahir", 25)` returns `Person` class instance and then using that you can call any of non static methods.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether an object is an instance of correct class you can use `instanceof` operator like :-

```
Person p = new Person();
 System.out.print(p instanceof Person) ; // will return true if p is an instance of Person
```

Moreover, if you are doing `Toddler.getAge()` (Toddler code not provided above), that might not work if `getAge()` is not a static method. You need to have an instance of `Toddler` class to call `getAge()` on it.

`public int getAge()` should be the signature to work like this `new Toddler().getAge()` OR

`public static int getAge()` should be the signature to make this `Toddler.getAge()` work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person aToddler = Person.createToddler();
Person aTeen = Person.createTeenager();
Person aPerson = new Person("me", 292);// using a constructor
  System.out.println(aPerson.getAge());
```

Notice the create toddler call in my code has no arguments? Your create toddler method should have no parameters because A. You're not using them, and B. they're unneeded for that method (expect maybe name).

That's how you can create instance variables using the code you provided. Hope this helps!